# Adding css class in runtime and trying to generate PDF via jsPDF addHTML but it skips runtime css

Tags: javascript, css, html, jspdf

I am trying to format HTML content at runtime by adding CSS classes and trying to generate PDF via jsPDF addHTML() method ,but PDF ignores the runtime added CSS classes
How I can resolve the issue.

```
  pdf.addHTML($('#pdfdownlaod').css('css1 css1'), function (){
           pdf.save('test.pdf');
           form.width(cache_width);
    });
```

and the css class is:

```
.css1 li a:hover, .css1 li a:hover ~ ul li a {
Background: rgb (81,112,135)!important;
}
```

Comment: `Background: rgb (81,112,135)!Background;`

? this is not valid. maybe that is problem. `!Background` is what?

Comment: It was by mistake. it is !important instead of !Background